# How or Where Cordova platform add android get the minSdkVersion value?

Tags: android, cordova, gradle, sdk, android-min-sdk

Good day,

I have a cordova mobile project, and I using "cordova platform add android" command to add my android platform.

In my config.xml, I set the minSdkVersion to 26 as follow:

```
<edit-config file="AndroidManifest.xml" mode="merge" target="/manifest/application">
        <application android:allowBackup="false" />
        <application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" />
        <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" />
</edit-config>
```

When I run "cordova platform add android" command, the "/platforms/android" folder and its files will be removed and auto generated. after it auto generate, I check the `cdv-gradle-config.json` file under "platforms/android", and found the "MIN_SDK_VERSION": 22.

May I know where is this "22" come from? or any mistaken I did to cause this issue?

My cordova version is `10.0.0 (cordova-lib@10.1.0)`.
My gradle version is 4.7.

Comment: Set this code in config.xml
`<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" />
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31" />`

Answer (score 0):

Set this code in config.xml

```
<preference name="android-minSdkVersion" value="22" /> 
<preference name="android-targetSdkVersion" value="31" />
```

This is the only tip that works.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).